# x axis tick mark labels of different length starting at same position

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, title

I have problems with the axis labels and tick marks in ggplot2.
The x axis displays different length classes, the y axis the number of individuals. How can I make all the tick mark labels of the length classes of the x axis start at the same position (at the top)? at the moment the shorter labels e.g. (51-60) are centered, whereas the longer (121-130) ones are written at a higher position. how can I arrange them so that they start at the same level/position in height? also I do not know why it does not display my x and y axis titles.

Thanks for the help!

```
ggplot(data=ALL, aes(x=Langenklasse_Zahl, y=Anz.10.ha)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Längenklasse")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Anzahl Bachforellen")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 84))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32"), 
  labels=c("31-40","41-50","51-60","61-70","71-80","81-90","91-100","101-110","111-120","121-130","131-140", "141-150", "151-160", "161-170", "171-180", "181-190", "191-200", "201-210", "211-220", "221-230", "231-240", "241-250", "251-260", "261-270", "271-280", "281-290", "291-300", "301-310", "311-320", "321-330","331-340", ">340"))+
 theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.3, size=15),
    axis.text.y  = element_text(vjust=0.5, size=15),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-.5, size=15),
    axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, size=15))+
 ggtitle("Längendiagramm der kanalisierten Strecke im Mai 2014") + 
 theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=3, size=20, face="bold"))
```

the data:

Langenklasse_Zahl    Langenklasse    Anz 10 ha
1   31-40   0
2   41-50   0
3   51-60   0
4   61-70   0
5   71-80   0
6   81-90   0
7   91-100  0
8   101-110 3
9   111-120 12
10  121-130 12
11  131-140 15
12  141-150 9
13  151-160 9
14  161-170 6
15  171-180 3
16  181-190 0
17  191-200 3
18  201-210 3
19  211-220 0
20  221-230 0
21  231-240 0
22  241-250 0
23  251-260 3
24  261-270 3
25  271-280 9
26  281-290 0
27  291-300 3
28  301-310 3
29  311-320 0
30  321-330 3
31  331-340 0
32  >340    6

Comment: Please add a minimal sample of your data. Without a reproducible example it is difficult to understand what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I added an additional column with 1-32 because the Langenklasse is somehow not recognized by my code. It is probably easier to just use the Langenklasse instead of rename al the tick marks.

Comment: Langenklasse_Zahl goes from 1-32, Langenklasse is the actual size, 31-40 and so on, Anz 10 ha is the number of individuals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your x axis labels in the same starting position, add `hjust=1` or `hjust=0` to the `theme()` elemet `axis.text.x=`

```
 + theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5, size=15,hjust=1))
```

Your axis titles are not displayed because you have to `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous(`) calls. Move the titles of axis to the same `scale_...` call where you provide breaks, label and limits, for example,

```
 + scale_y_continuous(name="Anzahl Bachforellen",limits=c(0, 84))+
```